# Inline-block se mueve debido al contenido

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo estas tarjetas en mi pagina, y tengo un problema con los estilos que no logro resolver.
Verán, estoy creando las tarjetas dentro de una etiqueta  esta tarjeta tiene `display:inline-block;` lo cual deberia alinearlas, y lo hace, el problema es que si el nombre del doctor crea una siguiente linea, es como que el siquiente baja para que el texto este al mismo nivel. No se porque ocurre esto.

HTML

```
<div class="tarjeta-especialidad">
    <img src="{{ URL::asset("img/png/user-icon.png") }}" style="min-width: 100px; min-height:100px" alt="">
    <p>Fichas: 7 </p> 
    <p>Dr. {{ $Medico->nombre ." ". $Medico->apellidos}}</p> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-cards a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block; 
}
.tarjeta-especialidad{
    width: 130px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #97d1da;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color:#363B3E;
}
.tarjeta-especialidad img{
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    color:#13ac4d;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega el atributo `vertical-align: top;` a tu clase `tarjeta-especialidad`

```
.tarjeta-especialidad{
    width: 130px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #97d1da;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color:#363B3E;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```